# Making class GuessingGame in Ruby, stuck on instance method guess

Tags: ruby, class

Okay, so I have an assignment to make a class called GuessingGame, and create..a guessing game! lol. But seriously, I have to make the game that takes input as an integer that's between 1 and 10. I have the skeleton of the class's syntax done, but when I get to the instance method guess, I'm getting stuck. If the user's guess is higher than the random number, it should return ":high". If it's lower than the number, returns ":low". If it's the right number..you get the gist.  I think it has something to do with my conditionals. Here is all of my code so far:

```
class GuessingGame

  def initialize(answer)
    @answer = answer
  end

answer = rand(10) + 1

  def guess(guess)
    if guess.to_i > answer
     return ":high"
    elsif guess.to_i < answer
     return ":low"
    else
     return ":correct"
    end
end

  def solved?
  end

end
```

Let me state here that I am very much a Ruby noob, and I'm just looking for some constructive advice here. Here are my rspec errors:

```
GuessingGame#guess returns :high when the guess is too high
GuessingGame#guess returns :low when the guess is too low
GuessingGame#guess returns :correct when the guess is correct
GuessingGame#guess changes solved? when a correct guess is made
GuessingGame#guess doesn't change solved? when an incorrect guess is       
made
GuessingGame#guess reflects the last guess
```

Comment: Why have you this commented: `#def guess(guess)`, What is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Oops my bad, didn't mean to comment that. It's not commented in my code. Here's the errors I'm getting:

Comment: # GuessingGame#guess returns :high when the guess is too high
# GuessingGame#guess returns :low when the guess is too low
# GuessingGame#guess returns :correct when the guess is correct
# GuessingGame#guess changes solved? when a correct guess is made
# GuessingGame#guess doesn't change solved? when an incorrect guess is made
# GuessingGame#guess reflects the last guess

Comment: Wow, can you edit and put that into your question in a format that's readable? Maybe what you want is `guess = $stdin.gets.to_i`

Comment: "didn't mean to comment that. It's not commented in my code". Then fix it in your question. We have to know what you're actually trying to use, since we can't see over your shoulder. Help us help you.

Comment: I tried formatting the question, and the code but you overwrote the improvements. It's really important for you to keep your code properly indented as that helps reveal syntax errors, especially with missing or extra `end` statements in blocks. Also, if there are spec errors, those need to be included as they are clues for the problem.

Comment: Is the new format more appropriate?

Comment: Show the spec error messages. I'd hazard a guess that they all contain something like "NoMethodError: no method 'answer` for `GuessingGame`". To fix this one, add `attr_reader :answer` to your class definition

Comment: Of course, there may be numerous other problems with the code you don't show us :)

Answer (score 0):

There is the my little review of your code. I guess It will not pass your specs but still..

```
class GuessingGame

  def initialize
    @answer = answer
    @solved = false
  end

  def answer
    rand(10) + 1
  end

  def guess(guess)
     if guess.to_i > answer
       :high
     elsif guess.to_i < answer
       :low
     else
       :correct
     end
   end

  def try_to_guess(assumption)
    result_of_guessing = guess(assumption)
    @solved = true if result_of_guessing == :correct
    puts "Your assumption is #{result_of_guessing}"
  end

  def solved?
    @solved
  end
end
```

First of all:

```
answer = rand(10) + 1
```

You should define function if you want to call it.

Next:

```
return ":high"
```

"high" is String while :high is Ruby-char. Its pretty close to strings and I guess you have a little misunderstanding in this one. Plus you don't have to use return, as ruby-functions return last calculated value by default, even in if-else statements.

Answer (score 0):

after your class definition, you have to set a variable to new instance of your class, then you can call the method.

```
 class GuessingGame
  attr_reader :answer
  def initialize
    @answer = rand(10) + 1
  end

  def guess(guess)
    if guess.to_i > answer
     return ":high"
    elsif guess.to_i < answer
     return ":low"
    else
     return ":correct"
    end
  end

  def solved?
  end

end

a = GuessingGame.new
puts a.guess(2)
```

since you are returning a string, it won't show it unless you call puts/print 
instead of returning, you could be putting that string instead.
also, you  need attr_reader :answer otherwise, you can't access answer from outside of your class and it won't work. go read about att accessors.
lastly, you can do @answer = rand(10) + 1 directly.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few notes on your original work.

- The `@answer` variable can be initialized directly, and
  must be referenced as `@answer` elsewhere in your code.
- In the `guess` method,`return` won't print
         anything to the console.
- You have no variable to hold the state of the game (solved or not
     solved).

With those issues in mind, here's my reconstruction of your code. I tried to stay as true to your intent as possible:

```
class GuessingGame

  def initialize
    @answer = rand(10) + 1
    @solved = false
  end

  def guess(guess)
    if guess.to_i > @answer
      puts "high"
    elsif guess.to_i < @answer
      puts "low"
    else
      @solved = true
      puts "correct"
    end
  end

  def solved?
    if @solved
      puts "You guessed it!"
    else
      puts "Keep guessing!"
    end
  end
end
```

The most notable changes:

- `@solved` has been initialized to hold the state of the game (`false` for
  unsolved, `true` for solved).
- Upon a correct guess, `@solved` will be updated to `true` in the `else` portion of the `guess` method.
- `solved?` prints information dependent on the state of the game.
- I've removed the colons from the `guess` messages. Since you're using strings and not symbols, they're unnecessary. Here's an [interesting article](http://www.reactive.io/tips/2009/01/11/the-difference-between-ruby-symbols-and-strings/) on the difference between the two.

Firing up IRB, here's what I get when playing the GuessingGame:

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > load './guessing_game.rb'
 => true 
2.0.0-p481 :002 > game = GuessingGame.new
 => #<GuessingGame:0x00000001803a80 @answer=6, @solved=false> 
2.0.0-p481 :003 > game.guess(5)
low
 => nil 
2.0.0-p481 :004 > game.guess(7)
high
 => nil 
2.0.0-p481 :005 > game.solved?
Keep guessing!
 => nil 
2.0.0-p481 :006 > game.guess(6)
correct
 => nil 
2.0.0-p481 :007 > game.solved?
You guessed it!
 => nil
```